# Google App Engine Search API and PhonenumberUtil not working

Tags: api, google-app-engine, search

While using Search API and PhoneNumberUtil in Google App Engine,
I am getting these errors even after loading the appropriate jars.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/Phonenumber$PhoneNumber

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/search/PutException
```

Attaching a snippet for PhoneNumber:

```
protected boolean isValidToSave() { 
    try { 
       PhoneNumber p = new PhoneNumber();    
       p.setCountryCode(this.getCountrycode().intValue()); 
       p.setNationalNumber(Long.parseLong(this.getPhoneNumber())); 
       return PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().isValidNumber(p); 
        } catch (Exception e) { } 
   return false; 
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add a code snippet which can give us an idea of what you are trying to do and how you are getting this error.

Comment: Attaching a snippet for PhoneNumber:                                                  
       protected boolean isValidToSave() {
  try {
   PhoneNumber p = new PhoneNumber();
   p.setCountryCode(this.getCountrycode().intValue());
   p.setNationalNumber(Long.parseLong(this.getPhoneNumber()));
   return PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().isValidNumber(p);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return false;
 }